# How to do decimal formatting dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task of formatting decimal values.I have a text box.The user can enter different values.For example- if it is 5 digits number  1,00,00
if it is 6 12,12,33 like this..
How can i do this dynamically?

```
function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var components = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    components [0] = components [0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6WpD/)

Comment: How is something just alert-ing the input field's value totally unmanipulated a "demo" of what you have tried?

Comment: Here's a slightly modified version of your code : http://jsfiddle.net/FPJH8/. What's missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the 3 in the regex with 2...

```
$('#number').focusout(function() {
    var a = $('#number').val();
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var components = a.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    components [0] = components [0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ","); // here in the regex put 2
});
```

Comment: You didn't test it, did you ?

Comment: @dystroy http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/t6WpD/1/ I did, why ?

Comment: 1) That's not the same code. You forgot to use the components. 2) And you're not handling numbers with a dot.

Comment: `components [0] = [...]` has to be replaced with `$('#number').val( [...] );`

Answer (score 0):

This code, almost equal to yours, seems to do what you want :

```
function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var components = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    components[0] = components [0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return components.join('.')
}

$('#number').focusout(function() {
    var a = $('#number').val();
    var newstring = ReplaceNumberWithCommas(a);
    if (a!=newstring)$('#number').val(newstring);
});
```

The changes :

- I rebuild the string by joining the two parts
- I return it
- I changed {3} to {2}
- I replace the value of the field

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/GkT4W/)